# "An error occurred while installing bootsnap (1.16.0), and Bundler cannot continue" when creating a new folder by rail's command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am newbie with Rails and here is my problem.

I created a new Rails folder by this command

```
rails new freelancer --database=postgresql --javascript=webpack
```

Here is the error I got when it created the folder

```
An error occurred while installing bootsnap (1.16.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

So when I checked in this folder

```
config -> locales
```

I do not see the file database.yml ?

So how can I fix all that problem ? Could you please give me some advices ? Thank you very much for your time.

Here is the full stacktrace

```
   create  README.md
   create  Rakefile
   create  .ruby-version
   create  config.ru
   create  .gitignore
   create  .gitattributes
   create  Gemfile
     run  git init from "."
   gợi ý: Sử dụng “master” làm tên cho nhánh ban đầu. Tên nhánh mặc định này
   gợi ý: có thể thay đổi. Để cấu hình tên nhánh khởi đầu sử dụng trong tất cả
   gợi ý: kho lưu trữ mới của bạn, cái mà sẽ ngăn chặn cảnh báo này, gọi lệnh:
   gợi ý: 
   gợi ý:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <tên>
   gợi ý: 
   gợi ý: Tên thường được chọn thay cho “master” là “main”, “trunk” và
   gợi ý: “development”. Nhánh vừa tạo có thể được đổi tên thông qua lệnh:
   gợi ý: 
   gợi ý:   git branch -m <tên>
   Đã khởi tạo lại kho Git trống rỗng sẵn có trong 
  /Users/anhbui/Desktop/Rails/freelancer/.git/
  create  app
  create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
  create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
  create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
  create  app/models/application_record.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
  create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
  create  app/assets/images
  create  app/assets/images/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  bin/setup
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/cable.yml
  create  config/puma.rb
  create  config/storage.yml
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/assets.rb
  create  config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb
  create  config/initializers/cors.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_7_0.rb
  create  config/initializers/permissions_policy.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/master.key
  append  .gitignore
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.keep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.keep
  create  log
  create  log/.keep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
  create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  tmp
  create  tmp/.keep
  create  tmp/pids
  create  tmp/pids/.keep
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor
  create  vendor/.keep
  create  test/fixtures/files
  create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
  create  test/controllers
  create  test/controllers/.keep
  create  test/mailers
  create  test/mailers/.keep
  create  test/models
  create  test/models/.keep
  create  test/helpers
  create  test/helpers/.keep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.keep
  create  test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  test/system
  create  test/system/.keep
  create  test/application_system_test_case.rb
  create  storage
  create  storage/.keep
  create  tmp/storage
  create  tmp/storage/.keep
  remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
  remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_7_0.rb
     run  bundle install
  Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
  Resolving dependencies...
  Using. rake 13.0.6
  Using. concurrent-ruby 1.2.0
  Using. minitest 5.17.0
  Using. builder 3.2.4
  Using. marcel 1.0.2
  Using. racc 1.6.2
  Using crass 1.0.6
  Using. rack 2.2.6.2
  Using. public_suffix 5.0.1
  Using. nio4r 2.5.8
  Using. bundler 2.3.26
  Using. mini_mime 1.1.2
  Using. websocket-extensions 0.1.5
  Using. timeout 0.3.1
  Using. matrix 0.4.2
  Using. regexp_parser 2.6.2
  Using. bindex 0.8.1
  Using. erubi 1.12.0
  Using. io-console 0.6.0
  Using. rexml 3.2.5
  Using. method_source 1.0.0
  Using. zeitwerk 2.6.6
  Using. thor 1.2.1
  Using. date 3.3.3
  Using. nokogiri 1.14.1 (arm64-darwin)
  Using. pg 1.4.5
  Using msgpack 1.6.0
  Using. websocket 1.2.9
  Using. websocket-driver 0.7.5
  Using. tzinfo 2.0.6
  Using. addressable 2.8.1
  Using. rack-test 2.0.2
  Using. sprockets 4.2.0
  Using. rubyzip 2.3.2
  Using. i18n 1.12.0
  Using. puma 5.6.5
  Using. selenium-webdriver 4.8.0
  Using. reline 0.3.2
  Using. loofah 2.19.1
  Using. webdrivers 5.2.0
  Using. net-protocol 0.2.1
  Using. activesupport 7.0.4.2
  Using. xpath 3.2.0
  Using. irb 1.6.2
  Using. net-imap 0.3.4
  Using. rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
  Using. net-smtp 0.3.3
  Using. capybara 3.38.0
  Using. rails-html-sanitizer 1.5.0
  Using. globalid 1.1.0
  Using. net-pop 0.1.2
  Using. actionview 7.0.4.2
  Using. activejob 7.0.4.2
  Using. jbuilder 2.11.5
  Using. activemodel 7.0.4.2
  Using. mail 2.8.0.1
  Using actionpack 7.0.4.2
  Using. debug 1.7.1
  Using. actioncable 7.0.4.2
  Using. actionmailer 7.0.4.2
  Using. railties 7.0.4.2
  Using. activerecord 7.0.4.2
  Using. sprockets-rails 3.4.2
  Using. activestorage 7.0.4.2
  Using. jsbundling-rails 1.1.1
  Using. stimulus-rails 1.2.1
  Using. turbo-rails 1.3.3
  Using. web-console 4.2.0
  Using. actionmailbox 7.0.4.2
  Using. actiontext 7.0.4.2
  Using. rails 7.0.4.2
  Installing bootsnap 1.16.0 with native extensions
      Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
      current directory:
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/ext/bootsnap
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/bin/ruby -I
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r
      ./siteconf20230202-5546-vke9r8.rb extconf.rb
      creating Makefile
      current directory:
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/ext/bootsnap
make DESTDIR\= clean
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path
      (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      current directory:
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/ext/bootsnap
make DESTDIR\=
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path
      (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      make failed, exit code 1
      Gem. files will remain installed in
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0 for inspection.
      Results logged to
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/extensions/arm64-darwin-21/3.1.0/bootsnap-1.16.0/gem_make.out
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:95:in
`run'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:44:in
`block in make'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:36:in
`each'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:36:in
`make'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:63:in
`block in build'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tempfile.rb:317:in `open'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:26:in
`build'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in
`build_extension'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in
`block in build_extensions'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in
`each'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:192:in
`build_extensions'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:853:in
`build_extensions'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in
`build_extensions'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in
`install'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:207:in
`install'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in
`do_install'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in
`block in worker_pool'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in
`apply_func'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in
`block in process_queue'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`loop'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`process_queue'
      /Users/anhbui/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/bundler-2.3.26/lib/bundler/worker.rb:91:in
`block (2 levels) in create_threads'
      An error occurred while installing bootsnap (1.16.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

Comment: Please post the full error message, including the full stacktrace.

Comment: @spickermann : thanks for your comment, I have been update my error message. could you please give me some advices ?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the Xcode command line tools. You can tell by this part of the error message:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path
      (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

You can find the solution by using Google to search for that exact error message which will lead you to [this AskDifferent answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a) as the top result.

To fix this problem:

1. Open a Terminal window
2. Run the command `xcode-select --install`
3. Follow all the on-screen prompts
4. Delete the `freelancer` directory
5. Retry the command `rails new freelancer --database=postgresql --javascript=webpack`

You can [read more about the command line tools](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/install-xcode-command-line-tools/) in a variety of places.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have been verified the xcode by this command xcode-select -p and it showed me that I installed the xcode already. But I still got that error ? Could you please give me another advice ?

Comment: You most likely installed them on a previous version of macOS and then upgraded macOS. Reinstall the tools either with `xcode-select --install` or with [these instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/375535/197811).