# Issue while installing JSON 2.6.3 in Ruby version 2.7

Tags: json, ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

While running the Bundle install, I am facing the below-given error. Kindly help me to resolve,
Ruby version is 2.7, JSON is 2.6.3

```
Installing json 2.6.3 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/private/var/folders/7g/95lyxbdd033gp04mqyx_hg_00000gn/T/bundler20230220-12004-po1nc6json-2.6.3/gems/json-2.6.3/ext/json/ext/generator
/Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/bin/ruby -I /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r
./siteconf20230220-12004-1nsrtrf.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /private/var/folders/7g/95lyxbdd033gp04mqyx_hg_00000gn/T/bundler20230220-12004-po1nc6json-2.6.3/gems/json-2.6.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

current directory: /private/var/folders/7g/95lyxbdd033gp04mqyx_hg_00000gn/T/bundler20230220-12004-po1nc6json-2.6.3/gems/json-2.6.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/7g/95lyxbdd033gp04mqyx_hg_00000gn/T/bundler20230220-12004-po1nc6json-2.6.3/gems/json-2.6.3 for inspection.
Results logged to
/var/folders/7g/95lyxbdd033gp04mqyx_hg_00000gn/T/bundler20230220-12004-po1nc6json-2.6.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-21/2.7.0/json-2.6.3/gem_make.out

  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:99:in `run'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:51:in `block in make'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in `each'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in `make'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:63:in `block in build'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tempfile.rb:291:in `open'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:30:in `build'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:169:in `block in build_extension'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:165:in `synchronize'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:165:in `build_extension'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:210:in `block in build_extensions'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:207:in `each'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:207:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/installer.rb:844:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:71:in `build_extensions'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in `install'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:204:in `install'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in `install'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in `do_install'
/Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in `block in
worker_pool'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in `apply_func'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in `block in process_queue'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `loop'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in `process_queue'
  /Users/user_name/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.12/lib/bundler/worker.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing json (2.6.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this error message:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

This tells you that you are missing the Xcode command line tools. Run the following command to install them:

```bash
xcode-select --install
```

Follow the on-screen prompts and then retry your operation.

You can read more at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75326102/3784008).